# How to insert mathematical formula/equation in Zotero's note?

Tags: equations, zotero

I've been exploring several reference manager by now and ends up using Zotero, because of it's simplicity. Previously I had mostly been using Citavi, which had this feature of storing mathematical formula written in LaTeX, which I had not found in Zotero.

How to get Zotero to store a mathematical formula? Is there any add-ons, or a workaround for this?

I would like to write the mathematical equation in LaTeX and save it still in LaTeX and not convert it to pdf/image. Is there an add-on that also serves as LaTeX equation editor and viewer in Zotero?

Comment: This looks borderline for on-topic to me. It's really about Zotero, which is a browser plug-in rather than a TeX tool.

Comment: well, it's yes and no, in a broader sense, take a look at questions with zotero tag they were also mostly about latex zotero integration, (note: the zotero which i mention here is the standalone version)

Comment: I did say 'borderline'. Is there a reason you can't just enter your LaTeX commands directly, _e.g._ '`This is a \emph{title} containing some maths: $y = mx + c$`'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By chance I've just found out how to do that!
Combine the [markdown-here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/markdown-here/) add-on with mathjax.

You can add the following code to the note:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({
MMLorHTML: { prefer: "HTML" },
tex2jax: {
displayMath: [['\\[', '\\]']],
inlineMath: [['\\(', '\\)']],
processEscapes: true
},
TeX: { extensions: ['enclose.js'] }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
Now your equation $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \pm c$
```

**Makrdown Toggle** in File menu (or Ctrl+Alt+M), and you have nice equations.[image]

Comment: Are you sure? I tried your method, but the equation is not mathjax, they are pictures.

Comment: @user15964 You are right. The script part is not used, because Markdown-here has math support enabled since version  v2.11.3

Comment: so do you mean before v2.11.3, the mathjax is working, right? Is it possible to make it work now?

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: There is no good solution with Zotero, nor is there an add-on.

Long version: There is no way currently to write complex mathematical equations in Zotero. Zotero supports UTF-8 (so greek letters work) as well as [simple html mark-up](http://www.zotero.org/support/kb/rich_text_bibliography) but nothing more complex (like fractions, squareroots, etc). Moreover, Zotero will *not* preserve LaTeX markup entered in Zotero fields. In other words, `\sqrt{5}` will be escaped to `\\sqrt\{5\}` on bibtex/biblatex export. There has been [talk](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zotero-dev/U9fGc1f3TO8/7o5Nr0uey-QJ) of either implementing ASCIIMathML or adding an option to leave LaTeX codes alone (such as exists e.g. for Mendeley). The former is still the preferred way forward, but someone has to do that, the latter has consistently met with significant skepticism from devs as it encourages data entry in a format that Zotero is otherwise unable to deal with (e.g. in generating its own citation). That all said, it isn't terribly hard to custom-hack Zotero's bib(la)tex export to leave LaTeX code alone and it might even be possible to convince the maintainer of the strongly recommended [better-bibtex](https://github.com/friflaj/zotero-better-bibtex) add-on for Zotero to implement that.

Comment: yes i accepted although it's not what i expected this is more than just an insight for me, so this means that if i wanted a new collection of several equations, i should write it in a separated .tex file?

Comment: probably using separate .tex files is the best you can do, yes.

Comment: Version 0.5.33 of [better bibtex](https://github.com/ZotPlus/zotero-better-bibtex) allows inclusion of literal latex by enclosing it in <pre>...</pre> tags

Answer (score 1):

Update: a better way to get Latex formula in Zotero is to use [Katex](https://katex.org/).

I have explained everything [here](https://github.com/MagTun/katex_for_zotero). Basically it's a TinyMCE plugin that calls the katex render function with a keyboard shortcut.

You can donwload the files, add them to `zotero.jar`, modify `note.html` and then use  <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>k</kbd>  to apply the katex style to the formula and the press  <kbd>F5</kbd>  to load the katex formula.

The two downsides from @yapphdorlw solution are fixed because Katex does not use a special mode but directly modifies the html of the note.

But there are still room for improvement.

[image]

---

*This was my first answer but the solution above has less downsides.*

This is an update on @yapphdorlw. I was able to make it works on Zotero 5 with Markdow-Here 2.13.4.

Here are the steps:

1. Download the code from [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here) and unzip the file
2. Go in the folder `src` and select the files/folders `chrome.manifest install.rdf common/ firefox/` (they are in `src`), and create a zip with them.
3. Change the `zip` extension into `xpi`
4. In zotero, open Tools>add-ons and drag-drop the xpi file on it, then reload zotero.
5. Open a note and write a formula like `$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \pm c$`
6. Press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>ALT</kbd>+  <kbd>M</kbd>  [not need for the script part from @yapphdorlw answer]

**Downside:**

1. The  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>ALT</kbd>+  <kbd>M</kbd> activates the Mardown-Here rendering (wrapper) and the changes made in this mode are not saved into zotero
2. When the Mardown-Here mode is activated, the sync can fails because the image created generates a source code that is more than 250k characters

**Possible error:**
If you get an error "The add-on "%S" could not be installed. It may be incompatible with this version of Zotero Standalone." when you drag-drop the .xpi file, it probably because the mentioned files/folder are not at the root of the zip but inside a folder inside the zip. When you open the zip you have to see the files/folders, not a single folder.

**Other sources:**
https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/59648/how-to-installl-markdown-here-in-zotero